# Rotate Circle with css hover

Tags: html, css

I created an simple website:[image]

So there is an circle above an image, i tried to rotate it on hover, but it simply wont worked! Heres my code!

```
<div class="image" id="landkreis">
<img src="reg.png" alt="" width="100%" height="auto" />
<span id="motha2">
<h6><br>Here<br>i am</h6>
</span>
</div>

h6 {text-align:center;
color:#f2f2f2;
font-size: 75px;
line-height: 74px;
font-weight:700;
margin: 0 5px 24px;
font-family: 'Route';}

#motha2 {
position: absolute; 
top: 1px; 
left: 15%; 
width: 300px;
height:300px;
border-radius: 150px; 
background-color:#4ec461 ; } 

h6:hover {transform:rotate(-90deg);}
```

UPDATEUPDATE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Ok the transition works but how can i make the hole transition smooth and that for examle it first rotates -15deg an then to 15deg and stops finally at 0deg?

Comment: are you testing in any specific browser or is it across all?

Comment: Pheeeeew so many answer with same thing..

Comment: You could work with delayed transitions (transitioning from one state to the same state is basically a delay)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations for the animation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need "rotates -15deg an then to 15deg and stops finally at 0deg"

You have to change

```
h6:hover {transform:rotate(-90deg);}
```

to

```
h6:hover {
    -moz-animation-name: rotate 1s linear 1;
    -webkit-animation-name: rotate 1s linear 1;
    animation-name: rotate 1s linear 1;
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    0%, 100% {-moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    33% {-moz-transform: rotate(15deg);}
    66% {-moz-transform: rotate(-15deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    0%, 100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    33% {-webkit-transform: rotate(15deg);}
    66% {-webkit-transform: rotate(-15deg);}
}
@keyframes rotate {
    0%, 100% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    33% {transform: rotate(15deg);}
    66% {transform: rotate(-15deg);}
}
```

Comment: sorry but didnt worked!

Comment: @EmSta: If it didn't work, why did you accept it?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using the prefixes?

The browser implementation is sometimes slightly different for new CSS properties. That's why there are a couple of prefixes used by the different browser engines.

```
h6:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform:    rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform:     rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform:      rotate(-90deg);
    transform :        rotate(-90deg);
}
```

See [**caniuse.com**](http://caniuse.com/#search=transform) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RDKTM/)

CSS:

```
div{
    border-radius:50%;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:green;
    text-align:center;
}
.rotate{
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;

    overflow:hidden;

    }  

.rotate:hover  
{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#motha2:hover {
position: absolute; 
top: 1px; 
left: 15%; 
width: 300px;
height:300px;
border-radius: 150px; 
background-color:#4ec461 ; 
-webkit-transform: rotate(7deg);
-moz-transform:    rotate(7deg);
-ms-transform:     rotate(7deg);
-o-transform:      rotate(7deg);
transform :        rotate(7deg);
}
```

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/VbZCX/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working **DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/4wLpE/1/
But in this example its not ratating continuously. if you want so, let me know.

- remove h6:hover
- add

  ```
  #motha2:hover { 
    cursor:pointer;
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have it working for Chrome: [Chrome test](http://jsfiddle.net/tYM9G/11/)

```
h6 {text-align:center;
    color:#f2f2f2;
    font-size: 75px;
    line-height: 74px;
    font-weight:700;
    margin: 0 5px 24px;
    font-family: 'Route';
    display: block;
}

#motha2 {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 1px; 
    left: 15%; 
    width: 300px;
    height:300px;
    border-radius: 150px; 
    background-color:#4ec461 ; } 

#motha2:hover {-webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);}
```

For other browsers: http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate

Smoother.... [Test in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/tYM9G/22/)

```
#motha2:hover {
  -webkit-animation-name: rotate; 
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s; 
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  to {-webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);}
}
```

Comment: Added how to make the movement smoother.

Answer (score 0):

Your example was working fine for me in firefox however it could be a browser issue. What browser you are on is very dependaent on what css3 code you can use. Also using browser prefix's might also help.

Take a look at my example here http://jsfiddle.net/yJH4W/1/ it seems to work on most modern browsers. If it doesnt work for you it could be because you are on a older browser that does not support it . To see what you can use a good site is [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com)

```
h6:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
-moz-transform:    rotate(-90deg);
-ms-transform:     rotate(-90deg);
transform :        rotate(-90deg);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h6 {text-align:center;
color:#f2f2f2;
font-size: 75px;
line-height: 74px;
font-weight:700;
margin: 0 5px 24px;
font-family: 'Route';
 -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;

    -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform;
    -moz-transition-property: -moz-transform;
    -o-transition-property: -o-transform;
    transition-property: transform;

    overflow:hidden;
- See more at: http://blog.vivekv.com/rotate-image-360deg-when-mouse-hover-using-css-3.html#sthash.r0C3747t.dpuf
}

#motha2 {
position: absolute; 
top: 1px; 
left: 15%; 
width: 300px;
height:300px;
border-radius: 150px; 
background-color:#4ec461 ; } 

h6:hover { -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
- See more at: http://blog.vivekv.com/rotate-image-360deg-when-mouse-hover-using-css-3.html#sthash.r0C3747t.dpuf}
```

Comment: Please explain what you've done. Throwing a block of code is hardly helpful (even if marked as accepted).

Answer (score 0):

**I did tried it on button and should work on Images too..This is what you just need.**
note: this code just uses CSS and HTML to make what you want.

```
     input#round{
    width:100px; /*same as the height*/
    height:100px; /*same as the width*/
    background-color:#05B7FF;
    border:1px solid #05B7FF; /*same colour as the background*/
    color:#fff;
    font-size:1.6em;

    /*initial spin*/
       -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
transform: rotate(-45deg);
    /*set the border-radius at half the size of the width and height*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    /*give the button a small drop shadow*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 15px rgba(0,0,0, .75);

    -webkit-transition:-webkit-transform 1s,opacity 1s,background 1s,width 1s,height 1s,font-size 1s;

-o-transition-property:width,height,-o-transform,background,font-size,opacity,color;
-o-transition-duration:1s,1s,1s,1s,1s,1s,1s;

-moz-transition-property:width, height, -moz-transform, background, font-size, opacity, color;
-moz-transition-duration:1s,1s,1s,1s,1s,1s,1s;

transition-property:width,height,transform,background,font-size,opacity;
transition-duration:1s,1s,1s,1s,1s,1s;



display:inline-block; 

    }
    /***NOW STYLE THE BUTTON'S HOVER STATE***/
    input#round:hover{
    background:#007DC5;
    border:1px solid #007DC5;
    /*reduce the size of the shadow to give a pushed effect*/
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0, .75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0, .75);


    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
-o-transform: rotate(0deg);
transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
```

It has several other beautiful features like pushed effect.Worth trying.Gracious.

> **note: You can edit transition duration and then another animation.Its you call.**